# Docker is not building container with changes in source code

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm relatively new with Docker and I just created an Node.js application that should connect with other services also running on Docker.

So I get the source code and a Dockerfile to setup this image and a docker-compose to orchestrate the environment.

I had a few problems in the beginning so I just updated my source code and found out that it's not getting updated in the next build of docker-compose.

For example I commented all the lines that connect to Redis and MongoDB. I run the application locally and it's fine. But when I create it again in a container, I get the errors "Connection refused..."

I tried many things and this is what i get at the momment:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node app.js
EXPOSE 8090
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8090:8090"
    container_name: app
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    container_name: redis
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb" 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

**up.sh**

```
sudo docker stop app
sudo docker rm app
docker-compose build --no-cache app
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Any ideas on what could be the problem? Why doesn't it use the current source code? It is using some sort of cache.

Comment: First thought, you are building FROM node:9. i.e. your application container version 9. Is this the version of the container that contains the latest change to your source? Also can you try a restart of your docker daemon?

Comment: Hey jesse. I Don't understand what you mean with the lastest change of my source. restarting the daemon didn't work :/

Comment: Can you paste the output from docker-compose?